# Media Queries with no CSS framework

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, responsive

I'm actually creating a small html/css page with 0 CSS framework, and I'm building all my media queries from scracth.

I'm wondering if it's normal to have so many breakpoints to cover, I mean when I use Bootstrap for exemple I just set the col for xs, sm lg ... and that's it.

Here I have to cover every breakpoints, from max-width 2560px, 1680px.. until small device, I even have for iphone 5, Iphone 6, Iphone 7 (even breakpoints for landscape when you turn your iphone), Samsung etc ... as they don't have same pixels.

Is this normal when you building your responsivity from scratch or I did something wrong in CSS ?

Comment: Tthis depends on the situation. Sometimes, a complicated construct that looks OK on a 1000px wide screen will need to be rearranged at 800px, and then it turns out to look terrible at 700px, so you will need another query, etc. But in most cases you just should design for a general range of widths, not specific width values. If you have a media query for 400px and one for 800px and the page looks OK anywhere between those values, there is no need to add a query for 480px as well, even if there are phones with that width.

Comment: yes, exactly so it's totally normal to have many breakpoints to handle then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breakpoints should be based on the *content of your site*. You should test your layout, **irrespective of device**, and once your layout no longer looks good at the given screen size, create a breakpoint and update the layout! Then keep going up (if you started with mobile) or down (if you started with desktop) until the layout looks like it could use another change...

Bootstrap uses breakpoints that work for *most average* scenarios but yours may be different. Bootstrap basically provides "phone", "tablet", "desktop" and "wide desktop" breakpoints pre-defined for you. It's merely a suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap breakpoints are already set  for XS SM LG, they are defined in pixels as:

- xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
- sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
- md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
- lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

You can **change all of these break points** BEFORE you **download** Bootstrap in the [settings](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints)

**But, you cannot add more breakpoints**. The only way to add additional breakpoints would be to write your own.

edit:

When writing your own breakpoints, most devs do not write one for every single device. you can usually cover a few devices with *one set* of css styles. so choose some that are close together, and format the page to expand across a few devices. For example, Iphone 5-6-7 and android devices within those widths can be grouped, then maybe add a change for the 6+ 7+ and other devices in those ranges.

have a look at [this graph](https://responsivedesign.is/news/2016/12/the-100-correct-way-to-do-css-breakpoints/) for the best groupings of breakpoints

Comment: I'm writing my owns breakpoints actually, but it is normal to have so many breakpoints to handle ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need that many breakpoints that indicates your layout does not resize well.

If you need different breakpoints for different iPhones my guess is you are using absolute values for widths and other UI elements.  You probably need to make better use of relative (`%`) sizing or look into using flexbox for layout.

There are more resolution variations than you can imagine. Your layout should "stretch" and "grow" well between a range of resolutions, using breakpoints just for making large sweeping layout changes. Breakpoints work best when used for things like changing the number of columns or moving a nav bar from the top to the side on desktop devices.